# How i can avoid this Status bar issue in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

In this below screenshot you can see when i present modally than the base viewController status bar is quickly hidden and when i dismiss this modal than is will quick show. so, How i can avoid this and fixed status bar when present modally.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: just give your UIView  top view constraint to safe Area and your problem solve

Comment: I have already given this constraint in navigationbar.top to safe area.

Comment: and did you give status bar color like your header color ?

Comment: its just constraints issue

Comment: yes @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: set as clear color to that view and can you update your question with your storyboard constraint screen shot ?

Comment: no, i want to same color in navigationbar and satusbar

Comment: show me your constraint then

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by using below code.

**Swift 3 & Swift 4**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
}
```

you can update the state once the view controller is already being displayed, you will need to call:

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden).

Comment: Thanks. you are right but when implement this the status bar was not hidden in modal because i want to present modal with full screen.

Comment: I got your point dear, But you can do it by writing override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true} method seprately for each controller

Comment: I also write in modal but not effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

I applied scroll view also in the same screen, by this code was able to resolve status bar issue.